# JavaScript game framework

Tags: javascript, canvas

Nowadays with `<canvas>`, it is easy to find all kind of cool stuff around the Internet. Like emulators, demos, games, just visual
stuff, etc.
But it seems that everyone is programming using the basic primitives of canvas.

There exist any framework working over `<canvas>` or utility library?

Comment: It would help if you gave an idea what you want to do on the canvas tag.

Comment: The goal is create a game where users input common sense data. 
For instance Fire burns... 
But create some game like and attractive interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look at something like Processing.js:

http://processingjs.org/exhibition

**UPDATE:**

If you want a game API, I haven't tried it, but the comments are promising, you can look at:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/gamejs-canvas-game-library

In order to keep the javascript small and optimized I tend to just access the elements directly, but, over time people will create libraries of their own, but it may not be libraries that are useful in certain situations.

**UPDATE 2:**

Looks like you can get a version of gamejs from here:

http://tommysmind.com/gamejs/GameJS-0.1.rar

This also was an interesting article on GameJS by the author:
http://tommysmind.com/gamejs/

Answer (score 3):

A couple of sprite based canvas libraries are:

- http://gamejs.org GameJs
- http://lamberta.org/doodle-js Doodle-js

Answer (score 2):

http://www.effectgames.com/effect/article.psp.html/docs/Getting_Started_Guide

Check it out - very cool!

Comment: Broken link? Gah character limit.

Comment: @Sneakyness - fixed (think that's the link he meant).

Answer (score 2):

The best is really [Akihabara](http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/).

Comment: The best for people who want arcade-style games *fast* -- definitely, but not for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

[jCanvaScript](http://jcscript.com). It's very simple to use and there are many examples at the site.

Answer (score 1):

**jsGameSoup** looks good:
http://jsgamesoup.net/

> **Batteries included**
>
> - Cross browser event handling (keyboard, mouse, touch)
> - Game entity management
> - Sprite management sprite.js
> - Sound effects playback with audio.js
> - Rudimentary polygon, box, circle collision detection collisions.js
> - Fast, deterministic random number generator random.js
> - Simple AJAX and bulk data loading with network.js
> - Basic cookie management cookies.js
> - Simple finite state machine statemachine.js
> - Optional auto-init to launch code attached to HTML canvases